# Send file without MultipartPostHandler (Python)

Tags: python, upload, urllib2

I'm using  MultipartPostHandler in file sending. My code is following:

```
params = {'file':open(file_name, 'rb')} 
headers = {'cookie':session_id}
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler))
response = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request("www.example.com/upload", params, headers))
```

How could I do the same (send file to the server) without using MultipartPostHandler? It would be good to use only buid-in python modules and urllib2. Is it possible.

Comment: What is the problem with `MultipartPostHandler`? It only uses built-ins, is freely licensed and the source code is available online.

Comment: MultipartPostHandler needs to install it using easy_install, pip or from source. I want like to write the python script that would not require new instalations.

Answer (score 1):

> MultipartPostHandler needs to install it using easy_install, pip or
>   from source. I want like to write the python script that would not
>   require new instalations.

Just add it to your original script - it is just one file. Copy paste the [code for the module](http://pipe.scs.fsu.edu/PostHandler/MultipartPostHandler.py).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct method available to post a multiple part file using urllib2. But there are ways to accomplish that by writing a custom form object using mimetype and mimetools module. You could [follow this recipe](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/urllib2/#uploading-files) and adopt your form to do a mutipart upload using urllib2.

(In Python3, urllib.request data can take a pointer to file object and that does read the whole file into memory)